# Possible Hypergeometric Model for Database Corruption after a Break-In

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A set of 1000 data items is stored redundantly in a database with 3 copies existing (therefore
there are 3000 entries in the database). During a break-in, 100 random data entries
are maliciously modified by inverting the letters and numbers. What is the likelihood that
the retrieval attempts for the first 50 data items (each retrieval attempt retrieving all copies
of a data item) result in three uncorrupted data copies (i.e. in the situation where all three
copies have not been modified) ?

```
I have identified this as Hypergeometric distribution.
Total entries= 3000
corrupted items =100
Uncorrupted data entries = 2900
P(none of them have 3 uncorrupted data copies) = (2900 c 150) / (3000 c 150)
```

Is my approach correct ? If wrong please help me find the solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your careful preliminary analysis before asking your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Using your hypergeometric model you have 100 corrupt items, 2900 good ones,
you sample 150, and want the probability of $X = 0$ corrupt items among
the 150. As you say, that would be

$$P(X = 0) = \frac{{100 \choose 0}{2900 \choose 150}}{{3000 \choose 150}} 
= \frac{{2900 \choose 150}}{{3000 \choose 150}} \approx 0.0054.$$

Evaluating the binomial coefficients is a difficulty because factorials
of large numbers are involved. In R statistical software care was taken
in programming the hypergeometric PDF `dhyper` to avoid overflowing
the capacity of the computer arithmetic, when possible. (The second method below
finds the log probability and then exponentiates that, just for additional
safety.)

```
dhyper(0, 100, 2900, 150)
## 0.005417104
exp(dhyper(0, 100, 2900, 150, log=T))
## 0.005417104
```

But if you try to compute the binomial coefficients directly, you get overflows
indicated as `Inf` for both numerator and denominator. I would be a rare
hand calculator that could handle binomial coefficients with such large numbers.

```
choose(2900, 250)
## Inf
choose(3000, 250)
## Inf
```

One might try an *approximate* Poisson model. The contamination rate
for one record is $\lambda_1 = 100/3000$ and the contamination rate
for 150 records is $\lambda_{150} = 150\lambda_1 = 5.$ Then, letting
$Y \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_{150}=5.3),$ you have $P(Y = 0) = e^{-5} \approx 0.0067,$ which is not horribly far from the hypergeometric result.

The approximation works best when 'sampling with replacement' would rarely
result in contaminating a record more than once.

Here is a plot of hypergeometric probabilties for contamination counts $0$
through $15,$
along with Poisson approximations. Out of 150 records it is unlikely to
see more than a dozen corrupted ones.

[image]

*Notes:* (1) Suppose two copies of a single record agree and the
third differs. Then you might be willing to let the majority rule.
It seems unlikely that two copies of the same record would be randomly
chosen for contamination, and even if so, that they would have
been randomly contaminated in exactly the same way. This raises the possibility
of a slightly more complicated model, which you might choose to explore.

(2) The computation with `dhyper` in R is *something like:*
$\frac{2850}{3000} \times \frac{2849}{2999} \times \cdots \times \frac{2751}{2910},$ a method called "zippering." In R, `prod((2850:2751)/(3000:2901))`
returns 0.005417104.

(3) For use in future posts on this site, in MathJax
you can write ${a \choose b}$ by typing `$(a \choose b)$`.